# how to set up 3-ring pure microphone in Ubuntu on some Dell notebooks

Tags: sound, dell, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Some Dell notebooks like 
Inspiron_5490_5498_5590_5598_Vostro_5490_5590,
Inspiron_5391_Vostro_5391,
Inspiron_7590_7591_Vostro_7590,
G3_3590,
when a 3-ring microphone(pure microphone device, not headphone or headset) is plugged in audio port, it cannot work, is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu, the headset and headphone can work automatically on these machines but for external pure microphone it need manually set up. Actually on these machines, there is also internal microphone that can work well automatically. So it is suggested to change to use the internal microphone or just use a headset instead if there is no special reason. If you do want to use an external pure microphone, here is the steps:
1. Online update Ubuntu to the latest with "Software Updater" application
2. Restart machine and insert microphone, enter Ubuntu desktop, click “show application”
3. Type to search “terminal”, in terminal type “alsamixer” to lauch the alsamixer application
4. In alsamixer application, press F4 or Fn+F4 to enter [Capture] view, and use left, right arrow to go to  table and use up, down arrow to select “headpone mic”, now the external microphone can work. You probably need do this manually setup for your microphone after each reboot.

If you want sound output from speaker when you insert external microphone,you can do following:
1. go to file /usr/share/alsa/ucm/sof-skl_hda_card/HiFi
2. comment or remove JackHWMute "Speaker"　in the file and save
3. restart machine